# Get functions in VS using macros

Tags: visual-studio, macros

How to get all the functions you have in a code file in Visual Studio using VS macros?
I`m using Visual Studio 2008.

Also I need to get whether function is private protected or public. For now I know I can just parse the code and check it on my own, but I want to make it in a proper way and think vs macros environment should allow know all info about functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [HOWTO: Navigate the code elements of a file from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006008.aspx)
An maybe [HOWTO: Navigate the files of a solution from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006004.aspx) would be interesting for you.

Getting function accessibility is easy. Following the first article, you have CodeElement object. If it is of type CodeFunction, you can cast it to CodeFunction (or also to CodeFunction2) type. The CodeFunction contains many properties including Access which is what you need. I have modified ShowCodeElement from this article so it only shows functions and also displays their accessibility:

```
Private Sub ShowCodeElement(ByVal objCodeElement As CodeElement)

    Dim objCodeNamespace As EnvDTE.CodeNamespace
    Dim objCodeType As EnvDTE.CodeType
    Dim objCodeFunction As EnvDTE.CodeFunction

    If TypeOf objCodeElement Is EnvDTE.CodeNamespace Then

        objCodeNamespace = CType(objCodeElement, EnvDTE.CodeNamespace)
        ShowCodeElements(objCodeNamespace.Members)

    ElseIf TypeOf objCodeElement Is EnvDTE.CodeType Then

        objCodeType = CType(objCodeElement, EnvDTE.CodeType)
        ShowCodeElements(objCodeType.Members)

    ElseIf TypeOf objCodeElement Is EnvDTE.CodeFunction Then

        Try
            Dim msg As String = objCodeElement.FullName & vbCrLf
            Dim cd As EnvDTE.CodeFunction = DirectCast(objCodeElement, CodeFunction)
            Select Case cd.Access
                Case vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessDefault
                    msg &= "Not explicitly specified. It is Public in VB and private in C#."
                Case Else
                    msg &= cd.Access.ToString
            End Select
            MsgBox(msg)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            ' Ignore
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Change it and execute ShowFileCodeModel macro then.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I`ve updated the questionm please, have a look.